# Code behaves differently depending on screen size

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing weird behaviour from my jQuery because my laptop screen size/resolution is somewhat smaller than an ordinary PC screen.

What I am trying to do is position a dropdown depending on where it'd fit best: if the event target is too close to the bottom of the window then you show the dropdown above the event target, and vice versa.

As seen here, if too close to the bottom, dropdown appears at the top: http://jsfiddle.net/u7n6tLgo/14/

And here, if too close to the top, dropdown appears at the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/u7n6tLgo/15/

```
$(this).on("click", ".selector > *[data-action='open']", function(event) {
    const selector = $(this).parent(".selector");
    const container = selector.find(".container");
    const title = selector.find(".title");

    container.toggle();

    let windowHeight = $(window).height();
    let titleOffsetTop = title.offset().top;
    let titleHeight = title.height();
    let containerHeight = container.height();

    title.toggleClass("selected");

    if(windowHeight < (titleOffsetTop + titleHeight + containerHeight) && containerHeight < titleOffsetTop) {
        container.css("top", (-containerHeight-titleHeight));
    } else {
        container.css("top", 50);
    }
});
```

I'm using a 15" Laptop, and for me the dropdown is always at the top, unless I zoom out my browser window to <80% (outside of the fiddle in my private project obviously; in the fiddle it is working as expected). I asked a friend of mine to try the code on his 24" screen and there it works fine.

For some reason the `title.offset().top` is above 1000, more than my window height, which my friend pointed out as weird. Not sure if that's why it's being weird. HTML and CSS is in the fiddles.

Why is it behaving like this? And more importantly, how do I fix it or work around it?

Edit:

```
<div class="selector">
    <div class="title" data-action="open">Open</div>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="itemList">
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add html to this? You got 2 different markups in the 2 fiddles, I don't know which one you are actually using

Comment: @Huangism Sorry if that is confusing; I use 2 different markups to demonstrate the two positions. I have updated the question with HTML.

Comment: Is that it on the entire page? Are you sure you only have one `.title`?

Comment: I only have one `.title`

Comment: I would suggest you edit the question and put more of your html here and some related css